# Laravel, how to get selected, db fields

Tags: php, laravel, select, orm

Have a model, from controller, I need access this Model db fields.

Code in controller:

```
$crud -> get() -> getAttributes();
//$crud->attributesToArray()
print_r($crud);
```

I was able to get entire table fields, but I need only fields, which are selected. Need dynamically show table with selected fields only, which can change during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a query:

```
$query = Crud::select('id as Id', 'name as Name', 'something')
             ->selectRaw('CONCAT(id, "-", name) as Serial')
             ->get();
```

Without knowing **what** the query is, to get a table that looks like this

| Id | Name | something | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | lorem | 1-A |
| .. | .... | ......... | ...... |

You need to use the `Builder` instance (before calling `->get()`

```php
$query = Crud::select('id as Id', 'name as Name', 'something')
             ->selectRaw('CONCAT(id, "-", name) as Serial');

$results = $query->get();
```

```php
dump($query->getQuery()->columns);
/*
[
    'id as Id',
    'name as Name',
    'something',
    Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression
]
*/
```

```php
dump(array_map(function ($column) {
    return $column instanceof Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression
        ? Str::afterLast($column->getValue(), 'as ')
        : Str::afterLast($column, 'as ');
}, $query->getQuery()->columns));
/*
[
    'Id',
    'Name',
    'something',
    'Serial'
]
*/
```

So you could that to a view.

```php
$query = Crud::select('id as Id', 'name as Name', 'something')
             ->selectRaw('CONCAT(id, "-", name) as Serial')
             ->get();

$columns = array_map(function ($column) {
    return $column instanceof Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression
        ? Str::afterLast($column->getValue(), 'as ')
        : Str::afterLast($column, 'as ');
}, $query->getQuery()->columns);

$results = $query->get();

return view('view', compact('columns', 'results'));
```

And then in your view

```xml
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      @foreach ($columns as $column)
        <th>{{ $column }}</th>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($results as $result)
      <tr>
        @foreach ($columns as $column)
          <td>{{ $result->{$column} }}</td>
        @endforeach
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You even resolved " as " field, and wrote view example. Your answer, solved my problem.

Code fails, if select() not used, but in that case, I just get fields with 
DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ". $table);
 
Strange, that Laravel, do not offer resolved fields  / field types directly, was much simplier with mysqli.

Sorry, I have no rep, to add plus to your answer.

Comment: I think you can still accept the answer I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'selected' database fields. If this is a list of column names coming from a form, you can simply pass that to the `get()` method:

```
$crud->get([
    'id',
    'name',
    'created_at',
]);
```

If instead you want a list of the available columns, you can't get that from the model itself (it is unaware of which columns exist). Instead you can use:

```
$table = (new Crud)->getTable();
$columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods, get() or all()

```
$crud -> get(['column1', 'column2']) 

$crud -> all(['column1', 'column2'])
```